# How to Fetch access data by Date in java

Tags: java

```
SELECT ItemName, SUM(Unit) AS SoldUnit, SUM(Total) AS TotalAmount,
       SUM(Profit) AS TotalProfit
FROM InvoiceTable
WHERE DateSO='"+dateTxt.getText()+"'
GROUP BY ItemName;
```

This is my Query but I got

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression.
```

In access database `DateSo` is of `Date/Time` type
Please help me.

Comment: What is the output of `dateTxt.getText()`?

Comment: Learn about prepared statements, and don't use String to represent dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you try something like this

```
private static PreparedStatement prepareStatement(
    Connection conn, java.util.Date date)
    throws SQLException {
  final String sql = "SELECT ItemName, SUM(Unit) AS SoldUnit, "
      + "SUM(Total) AS TotalAmount, "
      + "SUM(Profit) AS TotalProfit "
      + "FROM InvoiceTable WHERE DateSO=? GROUP BY ItemName";
  PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
  ps.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()));
  return ps;
}
```

Then use [ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery%28%29), make sure to read up on [ResultSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) and always [clean up after yourself](http://www.frischcode.com/2013/11/clean-up-after-yourself.html).

Finally, if you need a range of dates (use a BETWEEN in your SQL, and pass in two date objects)...

Comment: Catching Exception and ignoring it is one of the worst advices you can give to a newbie. Let your method throw a SQLException.